# PHP Apache Rewrite Rules and Variables

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get **action value** from variables in this url.

Real Url

```
index.php?action=ok&id=45&name=LG-Optimus
```

Friendly Url

```
home/ok/1/LG-P88
```

This above friendly url show when redirect an page like this

```
header('Location: /home/ok/' . $id . '/' . $name);
```

The page script that contains the code to get the variables

```
$ok = isset($_GET['ok']) ? $_GET['ok'] : "";
if($ok=='ok'){
    echo "<div class='popup'>";
        echo "<strong>{$card-name}</strong> added!";
        echo "";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

But i get 'Undefined index **ok**'.

The **.htaccess** file contains this code

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Rewrite for index.php
RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]


# Rewrite for card-name
RewriteRule ^home/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the GET-variable **action** to "ok", but your code presumes the variable is NAMED "ok".
   To check it in your code you should use:

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
if($action=='ok'){
```

---

Another thing, your regular expression lacks the "action" argument, try this:

```
^home/(.*)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$
```

Comment: Oh God. I changed the code, but still get the same error - Undefinex Index.

Comment: if you truly are using "isset" then that error should never appear, it sounds like you have a typo somewhere or that the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The problem is located in your header location redirect. This do not contain GET variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in this code. use this code

```
RewriteRule ^home/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-z_-]+)$ index.php?ok=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Also for security reasons you must avoid from direct use of $_GET . ([see](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php))